# Nuxt async fetch() doesn't update component property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a component that works perfectly with asyncData(), but i want to use fetch() instead. The problem is that when using fetch method, 'car' property is never updated. Am i missing something?

Doesn't work:

```js
data() {
  return {
    car: null,
  }
},
async fetch({ $axios, route }) {
  this.car = await $axios.$get('/cars/' + route.params.id)
},
```

Works perfectly:

```js
data() {
  return {
    car: null,
  }
},
async asyncData({ $axios, route }) {
  const response = await $axios.$get('/cars/' + route.params.id)
  return { car: response.data }
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the `fetch` hook with something like `fetch({ ... })`, you'll be using the old `fetch()` hook.

If you want it to work, try out rather

```js
async fetch() {
  this.car = await this.$axios.$get(`/cars/${this.$route.params.id}`)
},
```

As confirmed in this [github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9564#issuecomment-881580539).

Comment: Thank you. this is weird, so  we can use both of them, and the only difference is the parameter